# RESULT SET TO TABLE MODEL

Tags: java, database

```
public class showStudent extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form showStudent
     */
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    private Object DbUtils;

    public showStudent() {
        super("Student");
        initComponents();
        conn = databaseConnection.connection();
        showRecord();
    }


    public void showRecord(){

            try{
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "SELECT * STUDENT";
                ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
            }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            }


    }
```

problem here is the symvols are not found..
Symbol: method resultsetotablemodel
location: variable dbutils of type object.

Comment: Take care of java naming convetions. Class name should start with upper case character.

Comment: It is a guess but i think `private Object DbUtils;` must be removed and the correct DbUtils class must be imported

Comment: thankyou i managed to put that private object db utils. and a problem came up the symbol resultSetToTableModel cannot be found :(

Comment: been at it for a while now it's the only error now on my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils` at the top of your class, where the other `import` statements are located and remove `private Object DbUtils;`